# Is it possible to initialize a List on one line in Dart? (it's called a collection initializer in c#)

Tags: dart

Is it possible to initialize a list on one line in Dart?  Something like the following...

```
List<int> options = new List<int>{ 1,2,5,9 };
```

*(this is possible in c# and is called a collection initializer)*

Comment: Maybe read the documentation first: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/List-class.html.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Yes:

```
List<int> options = [1, 2, 5, 9];
```

I'd recommend reading:

- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/List-class.html

Comment: Thank you, the smaller the syntax difference the higher chance it will throw me when trying other languages :-)

Comment: List<int> options = <int>[1, 2, 5, 9]; also give type to the literals

Answer (score 21):

Yes, you can do it using the [List.unmodifiable](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/List/List.unmodifiable.html) constructor:

```
var options  = new List.unmodifiable([3,6,7,8]);
```

Or by using the  [List.from](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/List/List.from.html) constructor:

```
var options  = new List.from([3,6,7,8]);
```

Or just like this:

```
var options  = [5,7,9,0];
```

Answer (score 5):

There are also available **List.filled** and **List.generate** factory constructors:

```
List<int?> s = List.filled(5, 10, growable: true); // [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

This creates list of length 5, of type int or null, and initializes each element with 10. This list is growable, which means its length can be changed with a setter:

```
s.length = 10;
s[8] = 2;  // [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, null, null, null, 2, null]
```

After changing the list length, new elements will be initialized with null. If the list element type is not-nullable this will cause Exception.

**List.generate** generates a list of values.

```
var n = List.generate(5, (index) => 0); // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The created list is fixed-length, and each element is set to 0.

```
List<int?> n = List.generate(5, (index) => index * index, growable: true); // // [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

If we want to create growable list (i.e. we set growable to true) we need to explicitly choose non-nullable type eg. **int?** as we did here, otherwise increasing list length will raise exception. This stands for both List.generate and List.filled factories.

Good reads about those are:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/List/List.generate.html
and
https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/List/List.filled.html

Answer (score 2):

```
  var vals = <int>[1, 2, 3];
  var vals2 = List<int>()..addAll([1, 2, 3]);
  var vals3 = List<int>.of([1, 2, 3]);
```

Note that when we don't provide a type, we in fact create a list of a
dynamic type. Also, the `new` keyword is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize empty list

```
List<int> options = [];
```

Initialize filled list

```
List<int> options = [1,2,5,9];
```

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets define a `List`

`var listOfInt = [1,2,3]`

Curly brackets define a `Set`

`var setOfInt = {1,2,3};`

Curly brackets with colons define a `Map`

`var mapOfIntString = {1: "a", 2: "b"};`

It is possible to specify the type explicitly.

```
var list = <int>[1,2,3]

var setOfInt = <int>{1,2,3};`

var map = <int,String>{1: "a", 2: "b"};
```